# Where is "hddtemp" error logged after login?

Tags: debian, xfce, desktop-environment, fvwm

When I log into my debian box using XFCE and the xfvwm4 window manager I get the following error:

> "hddtemp" was not executed correctly, although it is executable. This is most probably due to the disks requiring root privileges to read their temperatures, and "hddtemp" not being setuid root.
>
> An easy but dirty solution is to run "chmod u+s /usr/sbin/hddtemp" as root user and restart this plugin or its panel.
>
> Calling "/usr/sbin/hddtemp -n -q /dev/sda" gave the following error:
> /dev/sda: Permission denied
>
> with a return value of 256.

The window box with the error then disappears as soon as I move to it. My question is NOT about the meaning of this error. Rather, it is about learning where these errors are logged. I have looked in the /var/log and cannot find this error. I have also checked in the ~/.xsession_errors with no success.

Any ideas where these errors go?

Answer (score 1):

If your init system is systemd, which is [the default init system for Debian 8 and later](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd#Introduction), then the error is likely logged in the systemd journal. That's accessed using `journalctl`. See `man journalctl` for details. You might also want to take a look at an overview or tutorial about `journalctl`, such as [How to Use journalctl to Read Linux System Logs](https://www.howtogeek.com/499623/how-to-use-journalctl-to-read-linux-system-logs/) or [How To Use Journalctl to View and Manipulate Systemd Logs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs).